# Android FileObserver in Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Is there a way to implement Java's FileObserver (that uses inotify) in Delphi XE7?

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Here is the Object Pascal wrapper class: https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/6e24b493338e85b895590cb775277ea31bfb16a9/android-19/android.os.FileObserver.pas

Comment: And here is the Java way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265906/how-do-you-implement-a-fileobserver-from-an-android-service