# Broadcast when user add new file to SDcard

Tags: android, service, broadcast

In my cloud backup application i want to upload any image in sdcard immediately create it -
 in other words - when user has a new (image) file in his sdcard, (for example, download from whatsapp/email/ added from PC by USB) run a function in my application..
I thought about Broadcast, there is any broadcast who can do it? another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android.os.FileObserver:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: thanks!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265906/how-do-you-implement-a-fileobserver-from-an-android-service