# how to get notify when new file is available on android external storage

Tags: java, android

i am writing an app that update it contents/records if new video files on the device meets certain criteria. so how to get notify(maybe through broadcast) when new videos files are available on android external storage so that the user can see his records when he opens the app even when the file was deleted. Not just new videos captured with the device camera(intent: android.hardware.NEW_VIDEO), i want to know as soon as when new video files are available(captured, downloaded, received, e.t.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) for this purpose.
It works for files and directories.
You will need to implement service for this. [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265906/how-do-you-implement-a-fileobserver-from-an-android-service) can be helpful.