# Does continuous running service affects/drains battery?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to observe the changes in a directory mostly the new file creations,
So I am using this methods described here -
https://www.darshanpandya.cf/blog/fileobserver-is-kinda-dead-whats-the-alternative/

My point is,
if I use the methods above in a continuous service like calling BroadcastReceiver from Service's onDestroy() & starting the service again from BroadCastReceiver's onReceive(),
will there be an excessive battery drain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`FileObserver`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) class available from API level 1.

```
observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch) { // set up a file observer
  @Override public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file + " was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
};
observer.startWatching(); //START OBSERVING
```

Another [example on Gist](https://gist.github.com/shirou/659180).
See also [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265978/6611700)